# Can we use member_group instead of logged_in/out?

Tags: members, conditionals, advanced-conditionals

I am creating a members only section and I am wondering if I can use the member_group variable, on its own, to check if a user is logged in or not. My assumption is that using both the logged_in variable and member_group variables at once creates a more resource heavy advanced conditional.

Basic example here:

```
{if logged_in AND member_group == "5"}
    logged in content (member group 5 view) 
{if:else}
    logged out content (public view)
{/if}
```

However, if users are not a part of any member group I create, or they are not a super admin, then they default to the Guest member group 3. This represents anyone not logged in. At least that is how I understand it.

But if EE identifies a user as belonging to any member group other than Guest, doesn't that mean they are logged in? If this is the case, then I should be able to use simple member group conditionals to check logged in status.

Does this sound right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `group_id` (or preferably `logged_in_group_id`) on its own - no need to include `logged_in` as well in the conditional.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there was a `logged_in_group_id` variable. Good to know. Thank you.

Comment: be aware though that logged\_in\_... variables are parsed late. Any tags between the conditionals are all parsed and only the resulting output will be discarded or shown based on the conditional.